# Apache rewrite with and without Parameters

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, parameter-passing

I need to rewrite URL's with and without parameters in the URL, I configured a `RewriteMap` via dbm

```
kronen-und-gehaeusetuben/wasserdicht-typ-pbbz.html => Produkte/Werke-Uhrenersatzteile/Schraubkronen-PBBZ-wasserdicht/
kronen-und-gehaeusetuben/wasserdicht-typ-pbbz.html?___store=default => Produkte/Werke-Uhrenersatzteile/Schraubkronen-PBBZ-wasserdicht/
kronen-und-gehaeusetuben/wasserdicht-typ-pbbz.html?___store=en => en/Products/Watch-replacement-parts/Watch-crowns/Screw-on-crowns/Screw-on-crowns-PBBZ-waterproof/
kronen-und-gehaeusetuben/wasserdicht-typ-pbbz.html?___store=fr => fr/Produits/Couronnes/Couronnes-vissees/Couronnes-vissees-PBBZ-etanches/
kronen-und-gehaeusetuben/wasserdicht-typ-pbbz.html?___store=es => es/Productos/Movimientos-Piezas/Piezas-de-repuesto-para-relojes/Coronas/Coronas-a-rosca/Coronas-a-rosca-PBBZ-hermeticas/
```

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    #ServerName www.example.com
    RewriteMap rewrite_DB "dbm:conf/rewrite.dbm"
    <Directory "/var/www/html">
        Options FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        DirectoryIndex index.html
        RewriteEngine On
        LogLevel alert rewrite:trace4
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteRule "^(.*html)" "${rewrite_DB:$1|/}" [L,NC,R=301]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

It works but how should I handle the parameters like `?___store=default`?
All HTML files without parameters work but not those with `?___store=default` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Just tested it, it seems to work but

`werkzeuge-verbrauchsartikel/schraubendreher/hormec-schraubendreher-zubehoer.html?___store=default Produkte/Werkzeuge/Schraubendreher/Hormec-Schraubendreher-Zubehoer/`

`http://1.2.3.4/werkzeuge-verbrauchsartikel/schraubendreher/hormec-schraubendreher-zubehoer.htmlenter code here?___store=default`

it get correctly redirected to `http://1.2.3.4/Produkte/Werkzeuge/Schraubendreher/Hormec-Schraubendreher-Zubehoer/?___store=default`

but the `?___store=default` should be removed (or not forwarded)

same for `werkzeuge-verbrauchsartikel/schraubendreher/lecureux-elektrische-schraubendreher-zubehoer/lecureux-ersatzklingen.html?___store=en en/Products/Tools/Screwdrivers/Lecureux-screwdrivers-and-accessories/Lecureux-spare-blades/`

`http://1.2.3.4/werkzeuge-verbrauchsartikel/schraubendreher/lecureux-elektrische-schraubendreher-zubehoer/lecureux-ersatzklingen.html?___store=en`

'http://1.2.3.4//en/Products/Tools/Screwdrivers/Lecureux-screwdrivers-and-accessories/Lecureux-spare-blades/?___store=en`

but the `?___store=en` should be removed (or not forwarded)

it work perfect for

`werkzeuge-verbrauchsartikel/schraubendreher/lecureux-elektrische-schraubendreher-zubehoer/lecureux-elektrische-schraubendreher.html Produkte/Werkzeuge/Schraubendreher/Lecureux-Schraubendreher-Zubehoer/Lecureux-elektrische-Schraubendreher/`

but in the requested URL it no ?___store=XX

thx Matthias

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: added an 2nd rewrite Rule
it works 

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^___store=.+$
  RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [L,R=301]`

i hope it is correct and a good solution

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule "^(.*html)" "${rewrite_DB:$1|/}" [L,NC,R=301]
> ```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* only captures the URL-path, which naturally excludes the query string. If you need to pass the entire URL (including the query string) to your rewrite map then consider capturing the value from `THE_REQUEST` instead, which contains the entire first line of the request, including the query string.

For example, `THE_REQUEST` server variable contains a string of the form:

```
GET /kronen-und-gehaeusetuben/wasserdicht-typ-pbbz.html?___store=es HTTP/1.1
```

So, you would write the rule like the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,7}\s/(.+)\sHTTP
RewriteRule \.html$ ${rewrite_DB:%1|/} [L,NC,R=301]
```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* simply ensures that only `.html` requests are checked.

You should probably remove the `NC` flag - by the look of your rewrite map, you are only matching against `html` (lowercase) anyway?

The `%1` (as opposed to `$1`) backreference contains the captured group from the preceding *CondPattern*, which is the URL-path and optional query string, less the slash prefix on the URL-path (which is also omitted from your rule).

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> AllowOverride All
> ```

You are allowing `.htaccess` overrides. If you have mod_rewrite directives in a `.htaccess` file then they will (by default) completely override the mod_rewrite directives in the `<Directory>` container in the vHost, so the rewrite map would never be processed.